# Why does Successful execution of Cron job stops further appending of log onto a file

Tags: cron, openshift, openshift-origin, persistent-storage

I am working on Openshift project. I configured a cron job using yaml config. In our application, all logs are appended to a file inside Persistent Volume. Once cron job is successfully executed to clear the file, further logs are not appended.

My observations:

1. Initially I thought PV itself isn't Read-Write Many, so I changed it to Read-Write Many and still observed the same behaviour.
2. There was some image issues, for the image mentioned in the cron job yaml. But I tried with different images and still observed same issue.

Can anyone explain me and find a plausible solution for the following ?

Edit:

Yes logs are being config as APPEND only while opening the file. I am aware about Access Modes to PV do not control over IO Operations.

Answer (score 0):

First you should check how the logs are recorded in the file on the backend storage of the PV. For example, the log files should be opened with "APPEND" mode, when the application start to log the messages to the file.
The PV access modes, such as ReadWriteMany and ReadWriteOnce do not control over the IO of the application perspective, it considers just only the nodes, not the pods and the applications. Refer [Access Modes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) for more details.

```
ReadWriteOnce -- the volume can be mounted as read-write by a single node
ReadOnlyMany -- the volume can be mounted read-only by many nodes
ReadWriteMany -- the volume can be mounted as read-write by many nodes
```

In other words, it means k8s does not ensure the file handling on the pods and the applications. Or the IO operations depends on the backend storage or filesystem characteristic, such as block(iscsi, ebs ...) or file unit(nfs, glusterfs ...) IO.